# When to use a cube to do data mining? SSAS

Tags: data-mining

I'm watching some video tutorials to learn how to use SQL Server Analysis Services.

Some videos explain how to create cubes and how useful they are.
Some other explain how to perform a data mining analysis.

But it seems that they don't mix both things, they don't create a cube as a data source for the data mining, they just use views.
Why don't they do data mining with cubes?

For example in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtFQv_B7YA8
They are using the decision tree method. 
Wouldn't you get some advantage by building cubes?

I've found on MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175645.aspx

> The Data Mining Wizard branches into two paths at this point,
>   depending on whether your data source is relational or in a cube.
>
> You do not need to have a cube or an OLAP database to do data mining.
>   Unless your data is already stored in a cube, or you want to mine OLAP
>   dimensions or the results of OLAP aggregations or calculations, we
>   recommend that you use a relational table or data source for data
>   mining.

When would I want to mine OLAP dimensions instead of views?

Regards

PD:

When I say a cube I mean...

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934081.aspx

wikihow.com/Create-OLAP-Cube-in-Analysis-Services

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube

Comment: Maybe this is something I should know about and I'm going to embarrass myself by asking, but what do you mean by "a cube" here?

Comment: I have added  the definition of Cube.

Comment: Thanks. And I just realized I don't know what a "view" is either

Comment: It seems a view is just a subset of data. What isn't clear to me: how is a cube different from a spreadsheet? This seems to me more like a technical/implementation question. Hopefully someone with OLAP-specific expertise sees this

Comment: ssdecontrol, a cube is multimensional and related to databases. I think you should read the definition at the Wikipedia

Comment: I did, but it's clear that I didn't understand it. In any case I'm not here to hijack your question with one of my own, I was just hoping to attract some visibility here